# What is the limit on TCP ports in Azure Web Apps?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/11/02/port-limit-for-an-azure-app-service/) blog, the limit on TCP ports opened in Azure WebApp is 1920 for S1, 3968 for S2, and 8064 for S3. Are there updated number for newer SKUs like P1V2/P2V2/P3V2? The RAM was doubled so I am wondering whether the number of TCP ports was also increased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there updated number for newer SKUs like P1V2/P2V2/P3V2?

These limits are there to protect the entire VM even though one particular site may be with its limits described above. The limits are different depending on the size of VM configured.

You could refer to this [article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#cross-vm-numerical-limits) which was edited 21 days ago.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I opened an issue on Github to have that doc updated with newer SKUs: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3081